# Let $f$ be differentiable everywhere. Suppose $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are Lebesgue integrable. Show that $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \infty$.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be differentiable everywhere. Suppose $f$ and $f^{\prime}$ are Lebesgue integrable. Show that $f(x)\to 0$ when $x\to \infty$.

Could I get some hints on how this could be done?

Comment: $f(y)-f(x)=\int_x^{y} f'(t) dt \to 0$ so $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) $ exists. It must be $0$ by integrability.

Comment: is this using fundamental theorem of calculus immediately?

Comment: I think the step where the limit must be zero by integrability in the comment of KRM, is exactly what you want to prove. So I don't think it's a valid argument.

Comment: Thanks Emiel, I'm thinking absolute continuity of f will have to come in to make use of f being everywhere differentiable. Still thinking of next steps afterwards though.